# Rails The action 'destroy' could not be found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've seen similar questions posted about this issue but the solutions offered there don't seem to be the problem for me.

I have a page where users can choose to edit or delete location files and it's coded with this each block:

```
<%current_user.locations.reverse.each do |l|%>
<%=l.address %> 
<a href=<%= edit_location_path(l) %> class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
| <%= link_to "delete" class="bg-danger", l, method: :delete,
                              data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<br>
<%end%>
```

I have in my routes (had both to try and fix this error):

```
 get 'locations/:id/delete' => 'locations#destroy'
 get 'locations/:id/destory' => 'locations#destory'
 resources :locations
```

And I have this coded in the locaction controller:

```
def destory
 @location = Location.find(params[:id])
 @deleted_address = @location.address
 @location.destroy
 flash[:danger] = @deleted_address + " deleted"
 redirect_to current_user
end
```

I can't figure out why rails can't find my destroy action (redirect works fine for other actions).

Comment: You have `def destory` and `get 'locations/:id/destory' => 'locations#destory'`

Comment: You should only need the resources :locations. Not sure why you have the two get lines in your routes file?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `method: :delete` in your link, which is correct.

The only other problem I see is that you spelled `destroy` wrong. You spelled it `destory` like "dee-stor-ee".

I would remove this route as well:

```
 get 'locations/:id/destory' => 'locations#destory' #=> wouldn't work anyways because it's not a "delete" request
```

since you are already calling `resources :locations`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :locations #-> DELETE url.com/locations/:id goes to destroy action

#view
<%current_user.locations.reverse.each do |l|%>
   <%=l.address %> 
   <%= link_to "Edit", l, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
   <%= link_to "Delete", l, method: :delete, class: "bg-danger", data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %> 
<% end %>
```

This will send a request to your `locations#destroy` action.

The issue you have currently is that you're calling `link_to` with some strange ordering:

```
<%= link_to "delete" class="bg-danger", l, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

... should be ...

```
 <%= link_to "Delete", l, method: :delete, class: "bg-danger", data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

As per the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to):

```
link_to(name = nil(link text), options = nil (controller/url), html_options = nil(class/id/data), &block)
```

Answer (score 0):

These issues jump out at me:

Firstly, fix `destory` typos.

```
# routes
'locations/:id/destroy' => 'locations#destroy'

#controller
def destroy
```

Secondly, use HTTP DELETE verb for `destroy`.

```
delete 'locations/:id/destroy' => 'locations#destroy'
```

Lastly, the link_to should specify the location path.

```
<%= link_to "delete", location_path(l), class: "bg-danger", method: :delete,
        data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```